# parallel computation with furrr on sf objects : future_map and map don't handle sf object the same way

Tags: r, parallel-processing, tidyverse, r-sf, furrr

I'm working on a `sf` points object.
I wrote a code to do some grouping and computing mean distance to the nearest neighbor and count by cities.

When I do all the processus with `dplyr` and `purrr`, it's working nicely (but it takes some time because my actual data is massive).
So, I just wanted to do some parallel computation with `furrr`, but it seems that if the `map` function works well on a list of sf objects, this is not the case for the `future_map` function.
I end up with the following error, `Caused by error in vec_size(): ! x must be a vector, not a <sfc_POINT/sfc> object.`

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

```r
# purrr version that's working 

library(tidyverse)
library(spatstat)
library(sf)

points_dist <- points_sf %>%
# remove points ID
  select(-clenum) %>% 
# pivot longer all the flag column (as date)
  pivot_longer(-c(geometry, City), names_to = "Date", values_to = "Presence") %>% 
# group by date and city code
    group_by(Date, City) %>% 
# split the df into a named list
  {setNames(group_split(., .keep = F),paste(group_keys(.)[[1]],group_keys(.)[[2]], sep = "_"))} %>%  
 # keep only the points that are here for a given date and city
  map(., ~filter( ., Presence == 1))  %>%
# get a df by date and city of points mean distances and count 
     imap_dfr(.,
            ~summarise(., 
                       Ra = mean(nndist(as.ppp(.), k=1),na.rm = T)/1000, # compute mean nearest neighbor distance (km)
                       Nagence = sum(Presence)), # count points,
            .id = "Group") %>%
    st_drop_geometry() %>%
     drop_units() %>%
  separate(., Group, into = c("Date", "City"), sep = "_") 

head(points_dist) 

 Date   City      Ra Nagence
   <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 flag00 418   0.0563       8
 2 flag00 430   0.410       12
 3 flag00 438   1.00         7
 4 flag01 418   0.0563       8
 5 flag01 430   0.410       12
 6 flag01 438   1.00         7
 7 flag02 418   0.0563       8
 8 flag02 430   0.410       12
 9 flag02 438   1.00         7
10 flag03 418   0.0563       8
```

Now I want to do the exact same thing but in parallel with `future_map` and `future_imap_dfr`

```r
# not working with furrr
library(tidyverse)
library(furrr)
library(parallel)
library(spatstat)

plan(multisession, workers = detectCores()-2)


points_dist_parr <- points_sf %>%
  select(-clenum) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(geometry, City), names_to = "Date", values_to = "Presence") %>%
    group_by(Date, City) %>%
  {setNames(group_split(., .keep = F),paste(group_keys(.)[[1]],group_keys(.)[[2]], sep = "_"))} %>%
  future_map(., ~filter( ., Presence == 1))  %>%   # this step doesn't work
     future_imap_dfr(.,
            ~summarise(., 
                       Ra = mean(nndist(as.ppp(.), k=1),na.rm = T)/1000,
                       Nagence = sum(Presence)),
            .id = "Group") %>%
    st_drop_geometry() %>%
     drop_units() %>%
  separate(., Group, into = c("Date", "City"), sep = "_") 

## i get the following error


Error in (function (.x, .f, ..., .progress = FALSE)  : 
  ℹ In index: 1.
ℹ With name: flag00_418.
Caused by error in `vec_size()`:
! `x` must be a vector, not a <sfc_POINT/sfc> object.
```

Below a sample of my sf points object for reprex.

```r
# a small reprex sf object

points_sf <- structure(list(clenum = c(980587, 98054, 980513, 980520, 980553, 
980571, 980599, 12052, 985032, 9850116, 9850168, 9850180, 9850192, 
9850255, 9850419, 9850441, 985621, 985634, 985666, 9856179, 9856230, 
9856250, 9856267, 9856289, 9856400, 9856587, 9856517, 9856234, 
9856455), City = c("438", "438", "438", "438", "438", "438", 
"438", "438", "418", "418", "418", "418", "418", "418", "418", 
"418", "430", "430", "430", "430", "430", "430", "430", "430", 
"430", "430", "430", "430", "430"), flag98 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1), flag99 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), flag00 = c(1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), flag01 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), flag02 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), flag03 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), flag04 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), flag05 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), flag06 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), flag07 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), flag08 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), flag09 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), flag10 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), flag11 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), flag12 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), flag13 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), flag14 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), flag15 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), flag16 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), flag17 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), flag18 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), geometry = structure(list(structure(c(4042673.64358386, 
2383567.60640022), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(4042282.31916301, 
2390340.82287981), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(4042223.43506352, 
2390290.84163531), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(4042135.56145553, 
2390338.71430411), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(4041953.40753155, 
2390204.54610263), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(4042202.44259419, 
2390199.71510174), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(4041953.40753155, 
2390204.54610263), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(4048241.63991944, 
2392475.82572007), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(3494010.63830182, 
2997650.75440965), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(3493956.39946714, 
2997554.96475846), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(3494032.15495681, 
2997531.65975932), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(3494032.15495681, 
2997531.65975932), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(3494032.15495681, 
2997531.65975932), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(3494172.20007342, 
2997575.87814808), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(3493908.8641747, 
2997703.04921459), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(3494032.15495681, 
2997531.65975932), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(3342382.633314, 
2805756.05766125), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(3342230.65029595, 
2805751.41488307), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(3342072.30450955, 
2805937.95663458), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(3342158.94953116, 
2805824.72334241), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(3342429.98390154, 
2804532.36764919), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(3342299.17426621, 
2805705.66517774), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(3342140.03080349, 
2805835.85122467), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(3342197.25975494, 
2805768.14774248), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(3342282.59901775, 
2805428.28042927), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(3342157.23216705, 
2805788.62580392), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(3339960.60730655, 
2807817.52139131), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(3346200.05093248, 
2805519.51740192), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(3346061.85639013, 
2805317.84414013), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 3339960.60730655, 
ymin = 2383567.60640022, xmax = 4048241.63991944, ymax = 2997703.04921459
), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "EPSG:3035", 
    wkt = "PROJCRS[\"ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"ETRS89\",\n        ENSEMBLE[\"European Terrestrial Reference System 1989 ensemble\",\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1989\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1990\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1991\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1992\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1993\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1994\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1996\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 1997\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 2000\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 2005\"],\n            MEMBER[\"European Terrestrial Reference Frame 2014\"],\n            ELLIPSOID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n            ENSEMBLEACCURACY[0.1]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        ID[\"EPSG\",4258]],\n    CONVERSION[\"Europe Equal Area 2001\",\n        METHOD[\"Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9820]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of natural origin\",52,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8801]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of natural origin\",10,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False easting\",4321000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8806]],\n        PARAMETER[\"False northing\",3210000,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8807]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"northing (Y)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        AXIS[\"easting (X)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Statistical analysis.\"],\n        AREA[\"Europe - European Union (EU) countries and candidates. Europe - onshore and offshore: Albania; Andorra; Austria; Belgium; Bosnia and Herzegovina; Bulgaria; Croatia; Cyprus; Czechia; Denmark; Estonia; Faroe Islands; Finland; France; Germany; Gibraltar; Greece; Hungary; Iceland; Ireland; Italy; Kosovo; Latvia; Liechtenstein; Lithuania; Luxembourg; Malta; Monaco; Montenegro; Netherlands; North Macedonia; Norway including Svalbard and Jan Mayen; Poland; Portugal including Madeira and Azores; Romania; San Marino; Serbia; Slovakia; Slovenia; Spain including Canary Islands; Sweden; Switzerland; Turkey; United Kingdom (UK) including Channel Islands and Isle of Man; Vatican City State.\"],\n        BBOX[24.6,-35.58,84.73,44.83]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",3035]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
29L), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(clenum = NA_integer_, 
City = NA_integer_, flag98 = NA_integer_, flag99 = NA_integer_, 
flag00 = NA_integer_, flag01 = NA_integer_, flag02 = NA_integer_, 
flag03 = NA_integer_, flag04 = NA_integer_, flag05 = NA_integer_, 
flag06 = NA_integer_, flag07 = NA_integer_, flag08 = NA_integer_, 
flag09 = NA_integer_, flag10 = NA_integer_, flag11 = NA_integer_, 
flag12 = NA_integer_, flag13 = NA_integer_, flag14 = NA_integer_, 
flag15 = NA_integer_, flag16 = NA_integer_, flag17 = NA_integer_, 
flag18 = NA_integer_), levels = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"
), class = "factor"), class = c("sf", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: This might be caused by putting a future inside a future.  Which step is the expensive one?  You should probably only have one future call.

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same error even if i stop the pipe after the `future_map(., ~filter( ., Presence == 1))` :(

Comment: Not sure.  It's a little hard to read the code because there is some unusual indentation.